# Dynamically set/override activationMode for local notifications

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, watchos-2

When a user responds to a notification on my phone, I'd like to conditionally choose whether to open my app in the foreground or background.

I am writing an app for the Apple Watch and when the user responds to a local notification on the watch I want to always launch the app in the foreground (no problem) but if they respond on the phone then I would ideally like it to respond differently based on whether the watch app is open at the time (WCSession.defaultSession().reachability.)  If the watch app is open then I will send a message to the watch and I'd like the phone app to remain in the background, but if the watch is unreachable then I want the phone app to open in the foreground.

Is it possible to dynamically determine the launch state of the app like this, or is the only way to set it ahead of time with UIMutableUserNotificationAction.activationMode?

Answer (score 0):

Could you always only fire silent background notifications and if you want the user to be notified, convert them to local (loud) notifications?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what I want, I'm just not sure how I can do that.  Does this mean just trigger a new local notification (in which case the user has to react to the new one)?